# Which FIR filter window to choose?

Tags: filters, filter-design, finite-impulse-response, highpass-filter

I need to design a high pass FIR filter based on parameters given. However I'm stuck at which window i should select. How do I calculate the parameter M?

The guide I referred myself to was behind this link: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/design-examples-of-fir-filters-using-window-method/

Comment: The window length. In the article you proposed, they select M by figuring the minimum window length necessary to have the desired precision. Since there is some benefits in using odd size window length they add 1 to get 41 while minimum size found was 40

Comment: In the previous article you can see that the transition band ($\omega_s- \omega_p$) can be used as an estimate of the required main lobe width and therefore find the window length from the given table. e.g. Hann window with transition band of $0.2\pi$ $$\frac{8\pi}{M}=\omega_s- \omega_p$$  $$\frac{8\pi}{M}=0.2\pi$$  $$M=40$$

Comment: Thanks for the answers. They were really clear. Didn't figure out to solve that for M!